# Inefficient random list generator

Tags: haskell

The following works but is terribly inefficient.
I suspect it is my use of list concatenation that is the cause.

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies   (runEval, rpar)
import Data.Text                     (Text)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T   (writeFile)
import Text.InterpolatedString.Perl6 (qq)
-- random data imports
import Crypto.Random.AESCtr          (makeSystem)
import System.Random                 (split, randomR, randomRs)


-- |This function picks a random element from a list
-- choose :: RandomGen g => g      -- ^ random generator
--                       -> [a]    -- ^ list to be taken from
--                       -> (a, g) -- ^ random pick
choose g lst = let ra = randomR (0::Int, length lst -1) g
               in  (lst !! fst ra, snd ra)
```

and

```
-- |This function generates a set of french SSN numbers
-- http://mon-convertisseur.fr/calculateur-cle-numero-securite-sociale.php
-- sans check digits
-- genFrSSN :: RandomGen g => g      -- ^ random generator
--                         -> [Text] -- ^ list of data
genFrSSN g = [fin] ++ genFrSSN g5
  where
    (sex, g1)    = choose g [1..2]
    (yBirth, g2) = choose g1 [70..99]
    (mBirth, g3) = choose g2 [10..12]
    (depart, g4) = choose g3 [21..95]
    commune      = 999
    (numOrd, g5) = randomR (100::Int, 300) g4
    -- using interpolatedstring-perl6
    -- because for some other generator I may have not have only Int data
    fin          = [qq|$sex$yBirth$mBirth$depart$commune$numOrd|] :: Text
```

which I rewrote in

```
genFrSSN g = runEval $ do 
    a <- rpar [fin]
    b <- rpar $ genFrSSN (snd sx)
    return (a ++ b)
  where
    sx           = split g
    (sex, g1)    = choose (fst sx) [1..2]
    (yBirth, g2) = choose g1 [70..99]
    (mBirth, g3) = choose g2 [10..12]
    (depart, g4) = choose g3 [21..95]
    commune      = 999
    (numOrd, _) = randomR (100::Int, 300) g4
    fin          = [qq|$sex$yBirth$mBirth$depart$commune$numOrd|] :: Text
```

But then instead of being low I simply run out of memory and cpu is overused.
The generator is supposed to give me an infinite list out of which I will take variable number of elements.
I use lists because of [Char] which is convenient when having multiple data input

Fistly, how do I get rid of (++)? And secondly please criticize.

Comment: You can omit the `++` by constructing the reversed list and then call `reverse`. But I don't think that this causes your performance problem.

Comment: If performance matters then use one of the MT implementations, not the `random` package.

Comment: I searched on hoogle but did not find any MT packages. Maybe the mersenne-pure94?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**

The `++` is not a problem. It looks like you only ever use it to prepend single element lists anyway.

**2**

Why not just `randomR (70,99)` instead of `choose g [70..99]`? That's just useless inefficiency. You can do so whenever you want to pick from a range of values in an `Enum` type. But in the general case, you can only improve the efficiency of `choose` (when you really need it) by making it work on a data structure with O(1) `length` and `(!!)` instead of lists.

**3**

The problem lies with the parallel evaluation. I am not familiar enough with that stuff to help you out there, but when I try compiling your program without the `-threaded` option, it runs quickly and with low, constant memory. Using `-threaded`, I get an out of memory error. I don't know why that is, but I don't think you should parallelize this stuff in the first place. The task is not inherently parallel.

Comment: Yeah, I had a punctual need for choose (not ranged list) and I ended up I don't know why using it anywhere.

Comment: Perf have improved a little bit but I is not the up to its counterparts in perl (I had to do one generator in perl due to convenience)

Comment: If you want to get performance up to par with Perl, you should post both source codes for comparison. This could justify a new question.

Comment: It is not mandatory to have perf corelation. But since one is compiled and the other interpreted, I did not expect a gap. Both algorithms being naive. Will post some benchmark when I have some time.